# How can I make the label and the el-input on the same line?

Tags: css, element-ui

```
<el-form>
  <el-form-item label="password" prop="password">
    <el-input type="password" autocomplete="off"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

It may be easy to change when not using elementUI.I want to make the label and the input on the same line and change the width of the input.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the label and input field on the same line can be done by using the following properties `label-position` and `label-width`

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        password: ""
      } 
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.7/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.15.7/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<el-form label-position="left" label-width="200px">
  <el-form-item label="password" prop="password">
    <el-input type="password" autocomplete="off"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried what you said and it does nothing.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example, It works here, so if it don't propably there is something else messing up the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, I have tested your code and it is right when I open a new project. I will check what leads to the problem. Thank you for your answer.